# Object Graph / Persistence Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, oop

I'm currently working with an online application that requires multiple screens/steps in order to complete. The application domain is modeled using an object graph. Persistence to and from a database is done using an ORM package.

As I progress through the screens I build up the object graph. Between screens I serialize/deserialize the object graph to the current session. By the time I reach the final screen, the object graph is complete and I store it in my database.

My question is the following. I'm not terribly concerned with patterns such as Unit of Work. I'm simply wondering if building the object graph beforehand, then populating as I progress through the screens and finally saving it is a viable strategy. Or perhaps populating/serializing/deserializing individual objects through the screens and then building the final object graph just before persisting to the database may make more sense. Or if there's an altogether better approach.

I've chosen to temporarily persist to the session as I gather the pieces due to the fact that if the user abandons the process it'll simply expire and I won't have to search a database to purge abandoned applications.

I hope my question is stated clearly enough. This seems quite common.

**EDIT:**

My main concern with my object graph approach is although I'm working in my domain model, I feel like each time I need to update a portion of it I incur the cost of deserializing / serializing the entire graph. Maybe I should have an intermediate abstraction between my screens and the final domain model. I'm using ASP.NET / C# as my implementation platform.

Comment: Are you worried about cost based on some measured performance issue? If not, then I'd first simulate the behavior you think will be expensive, and see if it matters in terms of your traffic plans. Save your worrying for your actual problems, not the more numerous potenial ones.

Comment: It's not clear what requirements led you down this design path.  Is rollback when the final save fails acceptable?  Does the user ever need to resume from the middle of the "wizard"?  It's hard to offer guidance without help understanding the constraints you are working under.

Comment: No rollback is necessary. If the user abandons midway then that's okay as well, there's no need to save partial apps. It's a simple series of screens. I'm just trying to organize the flow between screens to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I wrote an application like this, I had a distinct model for each step - a one-one correlation between data entity and user interface (mostly). Keeping the objects small and workflow-bound made it much easier to make changes to a single step or reorder the workflow, without forcing huge rewrites of the application.

Comment: @Jarrett Do you mean lot of small objects that comprise to a large object or all the objects independent ? .. just a doubt . .thanks

Comment: Just small objects related to small tables. I used a SQL View to recompose the "Big Object".

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly valid to just build up your session state in the HTTPSession and commit at the end.  If you need failover in this scenario, you can always use [Terracotta clustered sessions](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Sessions+Tutorial), which will store your HTTPSession state in the Terracotta server (with varying levels of persistence).  The server with the session could then die and Terracotta could resurrect it on another node.

You might check out [Spring Webflow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow) too - it deals with this sort of scenario in flow state (which is stored in the session too).

Comment: Would you build the session state using components for each screen or by pulling the object graph, updating it, then saving it back?

Comment: I believe in WebFlow, you can define state that has either page or flow scope.  I think I would do what makes sense for your app.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go with the option to

> populating/serializing/deserializing individual objects through the screens and then building the final object graph just before persisting to the database

for 2 reasons. Firstly if you build your application using smaller modules and piece the object graph together at the end it should make it easier to unit test and allow for parts/screen flows to be reused.

Secondly as requirements change over time there is a good chance that you will need alternate screen flows which will mean that you can't build your object graph up front and need to build your object as you go.

In posting my answer I've assumed that you have chosen the right technology model to fit the business requirements (see @Stephen C's comments).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that one possible (high level) problem with your current approach is that your users' work is not saved until right at the end.  This is not good if the screens take a long time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

What would building beforehand be good for? If you are not concerned with Unit of Work and long business transaction issues, then your strategy is the best for your situation...

Comment: I think this is more of an implementation efficiency issue / ease of use. It's intuitive to update the object graph as the screens progress, however, sometimes it feels cumbersome. So I'm just interested to see how others would approach this scenario.